# Capybara jQuery script works with Selenium driver but not Poltergeist

Tags: jquery, rspec, capybara, poltergeist

I'm trying to test a jQuery slider by executing a series of scripts in my Capybara RSpec test. My scripts do the following:

1. Grab the slider handle
2. Slide the handle
3. Release the handle

   ```
   execute_script("$('#PMPM-slider .ngrs-handle-min').trigger(jQuery.Event('mousedown', { clientX: 70, clientY: 77 }))")
   execute_script("$('#PMPM-slider .ngrs-handle-min').trigger(jQuery.Event('mousemove', { clientX: 100, clientY: 77 }))")
   execute_script("$('#PMPM-slider .ngrs-handle-min').trigger('mouseup')")
   ```

... and then runs my assertion. This test runs and passes using the Selenium web driver. Unfortunately, for performance reasons we run all of our tests using Poltergeist (we've kept Selenium around as an option for purposes of debugging, in cases like this). For some reason Poltergeist does not respond to these scripts (we're using the Capybara screenshot gem and I can see that the slider has not moved when test has finished).

Is anyone aware of any reason, related to syntax, configuration, or otherwise, why Poltergeist is unable to interpret these scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Poltergeist in this case uses touch events instead of click. Switching 'mousedown', 'mousemove', and 'mouseup' to 'touchstart', 'touchmove', and 'touchend', respectively, fixes the issue. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.